# How do you make a CCSprite appear as slanting like the star wars intro?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Skewing x and y coordinates doesn't give that kind of effect. Any ideas on how to achieve this kind of effect?  I already use cccamera but there are no examples on how to properly implement this. This image btw is from cocos2dx tried the c++ code still didn't work [image]

Comment: try the skew property, alternatively enable 3d projection and use CCCamera

Comment: Hi like I said I tried the skew(X & Y) but didn't gave me that kind of effect.  How do you go about using 3d projection?  I saw a recent post from you about CCCamera still didn't give me that effect.  Would you mind giving another sample code?  Thanks

Comment: Look at the actions with "3D" in the class name, they use 3D projection (and I believe require director's projection to be set to 3D rather than orthographic). If I remember correctly they use CCCamera to implement the effect but I could be wrong.

Comment: got it thanks! any idea why "camera/CCCamera" cocos2d v3 doesn't have it anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I feel I need to share this once and for all.  So this is how camera works when you want a slanting ,45degree or pseudo3d view of your background :

First set your director to 3d perspective

```
[director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];
```

If you only want some of the sprites to appear this way then remember this
all nodes have camera (cocos2d v.3 doesn't seem to have it anymore I don't know why)
so you do this:

```
[mysprite.camera setEyeX:0 eyeY:-40 eyeZ:10];
[mysprite.camera setUpX:0 upY:0 upZ:1];
```

Play with the values that fits your need.   Hope it will help others!