# How do you render and image with a camera perspective in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

[image]

Ok I've done this in cocos2d using CCCamera a few days back here is a link:
[How do you make a CCSprite appear as slanting like the star wars intro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905245/how-do-you-make-a-ccsprite-appear-as-slanting-like-the-star-wars-intro)

The upcoming version of cocos2d doesn't have the CCCamera anymore so I'm only left at doing it the hardcore way through OPENGL.

So how would I go about doing this using OPENGL?  This is for each image or sprite only when rendered.

Comment: without any knowledge of opengl an reply to contain everything would take too much time to write. I would suggest to see this tutorial: http://www.open.gl/transformations

Comment: thanks for the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of camera setup is called perspective projection in OpenGL. The "Slanting look" in your sprite is due to perspective division on geometry.

In case of fixed functionality, you can use the function
`gluPerspective(45.0, float(Width)/float(Height), 0.1, 100.0)`

Look at [this Python example](http://openglsamples.sourceforge.net/cube_py.html) for more details replace cube with a rectangle.

It is recommended though to use programmable pipeline.
you can find an introduction [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Introduction).

Very nice tutorial on [how to implement perspective projection in shader](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20Perspective%20Projection.html)

Answer (score 0):

The guy from Cocos2d pointed me out to a simple solution. Which was to override the draw/visit method and putting in OpenGL codes to do the trick.

```
-(void)visit
{
  kmGLPushMatrix();
  kmGLRotatef( 45.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
  [super visit];
  kmGLPopMatrix();
}
```

I subclassed a particular node(Sprites) and now everything works as planned.
But I appreciate and totally agree with your answers @Raxvan and @Bansal.

I'm now digging into OPENGL programming which is an essential. So I won't rely too much on game engines.